# Configuring a WAF infron of VPN gateway

Tags: azure, azure-networking

can we have a Web Application Firewall front of Azure virtual gateway in a site to site VPN connection between Customer OnPremises site and Azure VNet ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a WAF/Application Gateway to talk to on-prem resources. This is documented in the [WAF FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq):

> Q. Can I talk to on-premises servers when they are connected by
>   ExpressRoute or VPN tunnels?
>
> Yes, as long as traffic is allowed.